# NoClassDefFoundError on my machine only

Tags: java, jboss, richfaces, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run an application but am getting errors on my machine.  This seems to be specific to my machine only - others have no problem getting this to work and i've tried setting up my environment many, many times.  Could anyone give any suggestions on what is causing this?

```
04:23:59,627 INFO  [STDOUT] 04:23:59,624 ERROR ServeResourcePhaseListener:105 - Exception wile retrieving addResource
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/el/Logger

    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.util.ClassUtils.<clinit>(ClassUtils.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.config.MyfacesConfig.<clinit>(MyfacesConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResourceFactory.getInstance(AddResourceFactory.java:304)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ServeResourcePhaseListener.beforePhase(ServeResourcePhaseListener.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:96)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.app.package.filters.NewSessionFilter.doFilter(NewSessionFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.app.package.filters.Perf4JFilter.doFilter(Perf4JFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.el.Logger from
```

This is some additional information from the console, not sure if it is helpful.  Sorry for the formatting but it was initially in one large line so I tried to break it up.

```
BaseClassLoader@4198f74e{VFSClassLoaderPolicy@21944387{name=vfszip:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/ 
domain=ClassLoaderDomain@2d8816ec{name=vfszip:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/ 
parentPolicy=AFTER_BUT_JAVA_BEFORE 
parent=BaseClassLoader@6d575fa5{vfszip:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/}} roots=[ZipEntryHandler@215835978[path=app.war/WEB-INF/classes 
context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/classes], 
DelegatingHandler@455402463[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar 
context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@317477733[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar 
context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@1498879383[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@1682610771[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@1574564501[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug-2.2.0.GA.jar context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-debug-2.2.0.GA.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@264586326[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-excel-2.2.0.GA.jar context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear real=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-excel-2.2.0.GA.jar], 
DelegatingHandler@1611231792[path=app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-ioc-2.2.0.GA.jar context=file:/Users/user/Documents/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a6m2n-ng4vfl-i4xmq3n8-1-i4xmqccy-v
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the you are missing your Commons Logging classes in your build path.
Get the Commons Logging libs from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi and add them to your lib folder and also add them to your project Class path.

In case you are using some build tools like Maven for managing dependencies, add the following line in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am using maven and that is already in the pom file.  When I do look inside the ear file that is being deployed, I do see the logging library inside of /lib.